# Metasploit Default exploits folder

Tags: kali-linux, metasploit

I use the Security tube metasploit framework expert package.
in the 4th video of package with "Framework Organization" title, i see the metasploit exploits folder on backtrack but i'm using Kali Linux, in the Kali i couldn't find the default exploit folder!

I've checked these directories:

```
.msf4/modules/
opt/metasploit/
```

Answer (score 3):

Here we go:

**/usr/share/metasploit-framework/modules/**

You might also want to check the following website:

https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/modules-and-locations/